# How computer languages are made using theory of automata concept?

Tags: programming-languages, automata-theory

I tried really hard to find answer to this question on google engine.

But I wonder how these high level programming languages are created in principle of automata or is automata theory not included in defining the languages?

Answer (score 2):

Language design tends to have two important levels:

1. [Lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) - the definition of what tokens look like. What is a string literal, what is a number, what are valid names for variables, functions, etc.
2. [Syntactic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) - the definition of how tokens work together to make meaningful statements. Can you assign a value to a literal, what does a block look like, what does an `if` statement look like, etc.

The lexical analysis is done using regular languages, and generally tokens are defined using regular expressions. It's not that a DFA is used (most regex implementations are not DFAs in practice), but that regular expressions tend to line up well with what most languages consider tokens. If, for example, you wanted a language where all variable names had to be palindromes, then your language's token specification would have to be context-free instead.

The input to the lexing stage is the raw characters of the source code. The alphabet would therefore be ASCII or Unicode or whatever input your compiler is expecting. The output is a stream of tokens with metadata, such as `string-literal (value: hello world)` which might represent `"hello world"` in the source code.

The syntactic analysis is typically done using a subset of context-free languages called [LL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) or [LR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) parsers. This is because the implementation of CFG (PDAs) are nondeterministic. LL and LR parsing are ways to make deterministic decisions with respect to how to parse a given expression.

We use CFGs for code because this is the level on the Chomsky hierarchy where nesting occurs (where you can express the idea of "depth", such as with an `if` within an `if`). Higher or lower levels on the hierarchy are possible, but a regular syntax would not be able to express nesting easily, and context-sensitive syntax would probably cause confusion (but it's not unheard of).

The input to the syntactic analysis step is the token stream, and the output is some form of executable structure, typically a parse tree that is either executed immediately (as in interpretted languages) or stored for later optimization and/or execution (as in compiled languages) or something else (as in intermediate-compiled languages like Java). The alphabet of the CFG is therefore the possible tokens specified by the lexical analysis step.

---

So this whole thing is a long-winded way of saying that it's not so much the automata theory that's important, but rather the formal languages. We typically want to have the simplest language class that meets our needs. That typically means regular tokens and context-free syntax, but not always.

The implementation of the regular expression need not be an automaton, and the implementation of the CFG cannot be a PDA, because PDAs are nondeterministic, so we define deterministic parsers on reasonable subsets of the CFG class instead.

Answer (score 1):

More generally we talk about [Theory of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_computation).

What has happened through the history of programming languages is that it has been formally proven that higher-level constructs are equivalent to the constructs in the abstract machines of the theory.

We prefer the higher-level constructs in modern languages because they make programs easier to write, and easier to understand by other people. That in turn leads to easier peer-review and team-play, and thus better programs with less bugs.

The Wikipedia article about [Structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) tells part of the history.

As to [Automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory), it is still present in the implementation of regular expression engines, and in most programming situations in which a good solution consists in transitioning through a set of possible states.